# Dispatch redux action when clicking cell in react-table

Tags: reactjs, redux

How can I dispatch the action returned by the 'editUser' action creator when the client clicks on the `Edit` link for a given user in the Users table?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
import { editUser } from '../actions/users'

class Users extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>

                <ReactTable className="-striped "
                    data={this.props.users}
                    columns={columns}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const columns = [{
    id: 1,
    header: 'Namn',
}, {
    id: 2,
    header: '',
    accessor: 'id',
    render: (row) => (<a href="#">Edit</a>  ),
}
];

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users.users,
    }
}

function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ editUser }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(Users);
```

My action creator:

```
export function editUser(user) {
    return {
        type: 'EDIT_USER',
        user
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share your action code?

Comment: @Geraint My action creator is very simple just now.

Answer (score 0):

Take care of the click event

```
<ReactTable
  getTdProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
    return {
      onClick: e => {
        editUser(rowInfo.userId)
      }
    }
  }}
/>
```

You should probably tweak your action a bit too, usually you just pass the minimal data needed. In this case, user id.

Comment: 'this' is giving undefined for me

Answer (score 0):

how so I looked at this was that the `data` property needed to have the `editUser` action, so I added this to the data property.

```
const { users, editUser } = this.props
const newUsers = users.map(r => {
  return (
    {...r, editUser}
  )
})
```

then instead of `data={this.props.users}` use `data={ newUsers }`

that way, inside the render method of columns, `row.editUser` is available as an action.